# Печать `char*` строки в `UnicodeString` через `printf`

Tags: c++, unicode, radstudio, embarcadero

Как с помощью функции-члена [`printf`](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/System__UnicodeString__printf.html) из класса `UnicodeString` сформировать строку из аргумента с типом `char*`? Код вида:

```
UnicodeString s;
s.printf(L"%s", "привет");  // мусор
```

не работает ожидаемым образом. В частности, при попытке вывести на форму отображается абракадабра.

Если аргумент будет типа `wchar_t*`, то работает нормально (как с заменой строки формата `"%s"` на `"%ls"`, так и без замены):

```
s.printf(L"%s", L"привет");  // ok
s.printf(L"%ls", L"привет"); // ok
```

Проверялось как на Embarcadero RAD Studio XE, так и на RAD Studio 10 Seattle.

Comment: А с чего Вы взяли, что туда можно `char*` передавать? Я не знаю все эти борланодовские штучки, но если этот класс называется `UnicodeString`, и даже спецификатор формата он ждёт в `wchar_t`, то, по всем видимости, он хочет видеть все строки в `wchar_t`, т.к. это единственный гарантированный для него путь получить строку в UTF-16(UCS-2), вероятно.

Comment: @ixSci взял с того, что в описании есть сноска на стандартные спецификаторы формата, где указано и про `%s`, и про `%ls`. Ну и потому что [работает код](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/lqlJCMUJtXsyj3RM) с глобальными функциями. Правда, в RAD Studio он тоже не работает ожидаемым образом.

Comment: хорошо, а если английский текст использовать, тоже будет «абракадабра»?

Comment: @ixSci тоже мусор.

Comment: Ну тогда мне кажется надо в поддержку писать, похоже на баг

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ответ подсказали на [английском](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34513231/printing-char-string-argument-into-unicodestring-object) SO. Нужно использовать формат `%hs`.

Comment: ну это всё равно баг, я бы написал разработчикам этой среды. По документации к спецификаторам, `h` к `s` не применяется.

Comment: @ixSci по какой конкретно документации?

Comment: ну вот по [этой](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf), к примеру

Comment: @ixSci так никто ж не дает гарантии 100% соответствия Стандарту. У всех свои тараканы, типа `void main()` от MS.

Comment: понятно, но было бы неплохо такие вещи оговоривать в документации, а не создавать какие-то непонятные комбинации флагов, при которых всё работает. На мой взгляд это баг, либо документации, либо реализации.

Comment: @ixSci билдер и его наследие у меня вообще не вызывает большого доверия. Так что я уже смирился с их подходом к реализации. И если найдено рабочее решение, это уже хорошо. Багов там ну о-о-очень много.